# Are there any free tools to integrate in apps for evaluating speech on a word level?

Tags: resource-request, speech-recognition

I want to give the sound of a word and ask the user to repeat it.

In the app, I want to be able to check the accuracy of the user's speech and give him feedback on whether he said it correctly or not.

Is there any tool or code for this?